# Django - filtering on foreign key properties

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter a table in Django based on the value of a particular field of a `ForeignKey`.

For example, I have two models:

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)
```

I'd like to filter my asset list based on the name of the associated project.

Currently, I am performing **two** queries:

```
project_list = Project.objects.filter(name__contains="Foo")
asset_list = Asset.objects.filter(desc__contains=filter,
                                  project__in=project_list).order_by('desc')
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify this kind of filtering in the main query?

Comment: I am confused, is it true that `project__in=project_list` should be `Project__in=project_list` (should it case sensitive) since you assign in model `Project`

Comment: @ChauLoi, no think of it like just another field of the Model.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
Asset.objects.filter( project__name__contains="Foo" )
```

Comment: Thanks,
I had tried that but apparently I had forgotten to use double underscore.

Comment: is contains necessary??

Comment: @DeadDjangoDjoker `contains` describes the type of comparison used in the query that the django ORM produces, the sql will probably look like `LIKE '%Foo%'`.

Answer (score 26):

This has been possible since the `queryset-refactor` branch landed pre-1.0.  [Ticket 4088](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4088) exposed the problem.  This should work:

```
Asset.objects.filter(
    desc__contains=filter,
    project__name__contains="Foo").order_by("desc")
```

The [Django Many-to-one documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) has this and other examples of following Foreign Keys using the Model API.

Comment: Is this going to hit the DB twice, should I be using select_related() to make this more optimal?

Comment: You can add a .query.as_sql() to see what sql will actually be executed.

Comment: the link to the django docs is completely out of date and lands on a '410 Page removed' :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
student_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
available_subjects = Subject.objects.exclude(subject_grade__student__user=student_user) # My ans
enrolled_subjects = SubjectGrade.objects.filter(student__user=student_user)
context.update({'available_subjects': available_subjects, 'student_user': student_user, 
                'request':request, 'enrolled_subjects': enrolled_subjects})
```

In my application above, i assume that once a student is enrolled, a subject  SubjectGrade instance will be created that contains the subject enrolled and  the student himself/herself.

Subject and Student User model is a Foreign Key to the SubjectGrade Model.

In  "available_subjects", i excluded all the subjects that are already enrolled by the current student_user   by checking all subjectgrade instance that has  "student" attribute as the current student_user

PS. Apologies in Advance if you can't still understand because of my explanation. This is the best explanation i Can Provide. Thank you so much