# Django Filter by Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class UserTomonotomo(models.Model):

    userid= models.BigIntegerField(null=False, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email= models.CharField(max_length=100L, null=True)
    ######################
    ########

class UserFriends(models.Model):
    userid= models.ForeignKey('UserTomonotomo', to_field='userid', null=False)
    friendid = models.BigIntegerField(null=False)
```

I need to search for UserFriends whose userid > 0,

```
 UserFriends.objects.filter( userid__userid > 0 )
```

does not work as posted in [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties) !! What's the fix. I am using django version 1.5.2

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `__gt`:

```
UserFriends.objects.filter(userid__userid__gt=0)
```

See [QuerySet API Referenece - Field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) for other operators.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I actually need to check if userid is in a python list. How  can I do that?

Comment: @PratikPoddar, Then, use `__contains`.

Comment: @PratikPoddar, Accept the answeer if my answer was helpful.