# Using filter and order_by in a query

Tags: django, django-views

I want to make a simple blog that show 5 new posts in index page filtered by category. I read an other question told about this, but when I try it does not work at all

```
list_blog_canada = Blog.objects.filter(category_id=1).order_by('publish')
```

I am wondering this does not any problem, problem is in my model? or something

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

index.html

```
{% if listblogca %}
                        {% for entry in listblogca|slice:':5' %}
                            <ul><li><a href="/baiviet/{{ entry.slug }}/">{{ entry.title|truncatechars:25 }}</a></li></ul>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% else %}
                            <h4>THERE ARE NO POSTS</h4>
                {% endif %}
```

Thanks for your reading. I hope I will get your help soon

Comment: What does not work?  Your `listblogca` is empty?  You get some error?

Comment: @catavaran it shows list, but I want it was sorted by news to older

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get newest posts then you need to add `-` sign to the field name in the `order_by` method:

```
list_blog_canada = Blog.objects.filter(category__id=1).order_by('-publish')
```

Documentation for ascending/descendig order is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Comment: it works! this is what I want to, but I still don't understand what '-' means? Why we have to write it? Thanks you so much!

Comment: It is described in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Blog object does not have a `category_id` field.

Here is some documentation here for queries 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: if you are trying to filter based on the foreign key use something like
`blogs.objects.filter(category__id=1)`
*note that there are two underscores *

Comment: This question talks about something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. But Django can understand what category_id is. I used it before :)