# Django-DRF See all posts from friends

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just started toying around with the Django Rest Framework, so I'm still not entirely sure what exactly is going on. But I have a user model, a friend model, and a post model, I also have my serializers and views in order. But, I can't figure out how to return all the posts from my user's friends. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, db_index=True)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='photos', null=True, blank=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('username', 'password1'),)



class Friendship(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="friendship_creator")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name="friends")


class Post(models.Model):
    poster = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    body = models.CharField(max=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```
class FriendSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Friendship
        fields = ('creator', 'friend', 'created_at')
        readonly_fields = 'created_at'


class CustomUserSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    friends = FriendSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'image', 'friends')
        readonly_fields = 'image'
```

views.py

```
class FriendViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FriendSerializer


class UserProfileViewSet(RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you started,

So what you need to do first is get all the friends, you can do that by using

```
friends = <user_objects>.Friendship_set.all()
```

Read more about is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Now that you have all the friends of that particular user, covert their IDs to list and use the in list filter.

```
Post.objects.filter(poster__id__in=[list_of_ids_of_friends])
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties) for filtering on foreign key properties.