# Django: extend User model with profile onetoonefield errors

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from my_app.models import Teams

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I then go into the shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

when I type

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', password='test')
```

I unsurprisingly get

```
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: my_app_profile.team_id
```

but when I type

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', password='test', team='developer')
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'team' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

If I type

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', password='test', profile.team='developer')
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Any help, hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post your `User` and `Teams` models and how you are saving to `Profile` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allowed team to be null, so when you create a profile like so:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # Team isn't defined
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

You will get an error.

Allow team to be null (or set a default in the code above):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens. Is there no way to add the team information into the **kwargs in the User.objects.create_user() or am I constrained to this method below:
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
>>> freds_department = u.employee.department

Comment: No - you have to create the User object separately before you can create a Profile for the user

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', password='test')
```

you get `IntegrityError` because of `post_save` signal. It tries to create a `Profile` instance but in `Profile` model `team` cannot be `NULL`. [By default, model fields have `null=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null).

When you run

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', 
    password='test', team='developer')
```

you get error because `team` is a field in `Profile` model, not `User` model.

When you run

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', email='dummyemail@dum.com', 
    password='test', profile.team='developer')
```

you get error because you cannot use `.` to refer attributes. You need to use `__` to filter on foreign key properties. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties) question for example. However, even if you use `__`, it will still give error because their is no field named `profile` in `User` model.

One more thing I would suggest is to combine both `post_save` signals into one because both have same sender.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) about `ForeignKey.related_name`. By default, OneToOneField have related name to join one model to an ohter, but ForeignKey don't. Just have this option and you can do `user.team` to access to the model related.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Teams, 
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='team',
                             null=True)
```

Comment: He's not having issues accessing the related objects, he's having issues creating one in the first place.

Comment: My fault bad reading. You initial your object `Profile`, but model wait a value for `team`, add `null=True`. And it's work because you allow save model with null field.