# How to three-level query in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have three tables, names `A`, `B`, `C`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    a = models.ForeignKey(to=A)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(to=B)
```

I want get the bellow data:

```
[
    {"name":"a1",
     "data":[{
        "name":"b1",
        "data":[
           {"name":"c1",
           "data":{"c1_name":"c1_name", "c1_id":"c1_id"}
           },
           {"name":"c2",
           "data":{"c2_name":"c2_name", "c2_id":"c2_id"}
           }
        ] 
     },
    {
        "name":"b2",
        "data":[
           {"name":"c1",
           "data":{"c1_name":"c1_name", "c1_id":"c1_id"}
           },
           {"name":"c2",
           "data":{"c2_name":"c2_name", "c2_id":"c2_id"}
           }
          ] 
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

You see, there is three-level data, if there is only table A and B, I can multi-table connection query:

```
B.objects.filter(a='search_id')
```

But now there is three tables, and you see the table `C`'s email is not contain in the query data. 
How to realize this requirement in my scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties)

Comment: @BrianH. My scenario is three-level connection, yours is two.

Comment: you can use the foreignkey as a property and add another `__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brian H. is pointing out in the comments, you can chain foreign keys with `__`.

In your case you could get the data with

```
C.objects.filter(b__a='search_id').values('id', 'name', 'b__name', 'b__a__name')
```

You can then loop through the data and build the list in the format you require.