# Django dynamic Url problem- invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: django, url, dynamic-url

I'm trying to make a dynamic url that adds the name of the current user to the path when he tries to go to his personal posts page.
In the personalposts page I filtered all the posts and showed a list of the posts of the current user only. I just want to add his name to the url also. thats it.
I tried a lot of things and failed. I have a feeling that the problem is that the author refers to the Django's built-in User model.

My code:

url:

```
    path('<username>/', views.personalposts, name='personalposts'),
```

The view:

Before the view was:

```
def personalposts(request, username):
    items = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    return render(request, 'TheApp/personalposts.html', {'items':items})
```

I still want to display the personal posts like this. It works but with out the dynamic url.

Now I changed it to:

```
def personalposts(request, username):
    items = Post.objects.get(author=username)

    return render(request, 'TheApp/personalposts.html', {'items':items})
```

The model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    #כדי שרק משתמשים רשומים יוכלו ליצור פוסט
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

in

```
items = Post.objects.get(author=username)
```

you check if the author field is the same as the user name, you can look up FK fields like this:

```
items = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)
```

but pay attention that if you got multiple authors with the same username it will break.

This is similar to: [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties)

EDIT: corrected to filter

EDIT: to check that only the user itself can see the posts:

```
def personalposts(request, username):
    if username == request.user.username:
        items = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)
        return render(request, 'TheApp/personalposts.html', {'items':items})
    else:
        # handle it
        raise PermissionDenied() # as a example
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to do it with author.username and it did not work. Its because in case of query you should use lookups right?

Comment: And about the multiple, now it says:"get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 2". Why its a problem? I think that's why I need to filter and not to use Get.
Anyway what I'm trying to understand is how all of this works. I want to use a dynamic url so I write it in the Path for example: <username>. The 2nd step is to get it as a parameter in my view func right? and then how can I set it? I dont get this part

Comment: yes you should use filter, sorry for that...

and then its author__username  the __ are important


what do you mean by set it?  in your html where you display the link to the url you use something like {% url my_view username=request.user.username %} 

according to the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: Yea did it and worked.. but if i enter the url path manually and write anything instead of the user.username its still works.. I want that only with the user.user name as <username> it will work

Comment: Because I want that each <username> in the path will lead to this username's posts. Now I can write whatever I want and it will display the current user posts.. I want him to access this posts page only with his username in the path.. got me?

Comment: aaah  yes

you have to do a check in the view:

if request.user.username == username:
    do_stuff
else:
     raise PermissionDenied() #or do something else...

Comment: Yea I know this 1.. but still i can write anything i want in the url <username> area and it still show me the page with out problems.. I want that the only valid url will be the current username

Comment: i adjusted the answer if you do a check like this then only the logged in username is working... otherwise it should show a 403 page

Comment: items = Post.objects.filter(author__username=username)

Yea thank just wrote this line too and it answered my answer! I guess explaining you're problam to someone realy helps figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

K found one problem! In my base.html I used Realtive Url and it expected and paramater.
But now I can write anything in url and its still work..