# Filtering on foreignkey properties doesn't filter out the foreignkey objects

Tags: django

I have Equipment that can be booked (Bookings). But I don't want to show the bookings from the past.

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Booking(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, related_name='bookings', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

queryset = Equipment.objects.filter(bookings__start_date__gte=datetime.now().date()).distinct()
```

But this query still contains all the bookings that have startdates in the past.
Any ideas?

Comment: post your models please

Comment: you have a typo in queryset, remove the 's' before start_date

Comment: Sorry @bmons, I now have a related_name called bookings. But still the same result .. do you have any more ideas?

Comment: check these example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties,