# django how to use filter for ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, categories

I'm having trouble filtering by category.

```
category = ['fruits', 'vegetable']
post = ['apple', 'banana', 'onion']
```

python 3 / django 3

### project/app/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category =  models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

### category

```
category1 name=fruits
category2 name=vegetable
```

### post

```
post1 title=apple category=fruits
post2 title=banana category=fruits
post3 title=onion category=vegetable
```

### python manage.py shell

```
>>> from post.models import *
>>> category = Category.objects.all()
>>> print(category)
<QuerySet [<Category: vegetable>, <Category: fruits>]>
>>> post = Post.objects.all()
>>> print(post)
<QuerySet [<Post: apple>, <Post: banana>, <Post: onion>]>
```

### views.py work !!!

```
def category(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    post = Post.objects.filter(category__name='vegetable')
    category_key = Category.objects.get(name=pk)
    return render(request, 'post/list.html', {'post':post, 'category':category})
```

### views.py Not working :(

```
def category(request, category_name, pk):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    post = Post.objects.filter(category__name=category_name)
    category_key = Category.objects.get(name=pk)
    return render(request, 'post/list.html', {'post':post, 'category':category})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties)

Answer (score 7):

You can filter on the `Category` object:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category_object)
```

or if you do not have a `Category` object, filter on the name of the category by using double underscores `__`:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(category__name=category_name)
```

So you can obtain the `Post` objects related to `fruits` with:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(category__name='fruits')
```

Answer (score -1):

posts = Post.objects.filter(category = Category.objects.get('name' = **Whatever_you_are_searching_for**))