# query ForeignKey of model

Tags: python, django, django-models

**I want get all orders of customer whose id = 3 **

*----------------------------------------------------------------*

```
class customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('pending','pending'),
        ('out for delivery','out for delivery'),
        ('deliveried','deliveried')
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , null=True,choices=STATUS)
    customer= models.ForeignKey(customer,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(product,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties)

Comment: `order.objects.filter(customer_id=3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to do it.

### One way is from order objects:

```
order.objects.filter(customer__id=3)
```

### Second from customer objects:

```
customer.objects.get(id=3).order_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

its actually quite simple.
just do the  following
order.objects.filter(customer_id=3)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **filter** method provided by Django model class

This method returns all the orders in a query-set object.
so one more question might raise is where we should actually use this method?

You can actually do this in your **views.py**

Example:

**urls.py**

```
path('my_view/<int:id>',views.my_order,name="my_order")
```

**views.py**

```
def my_order(request,id):
    my_orders = order.objects.filter(customer_id=3) #this will return a query set
    return render(request,'index.html',{'my_orders':my_orders})
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
{% for o in my_orders %}
       {{o}}
{% endfor %}
</body>
```