# Django framework filtering on foreign key properties

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False,default=True)
    is_avaliable = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False,default=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False,default=0)
```

WHERE cart is using restaurant as a foreign key.

In views.py:

```
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
            userid = request.user.id
            res= request.data.get('restaurant', False)
            cartItem = Cart.objects.filter(user=userid,item__restaurant__contains=res)
```

It is throwing an error saying:

```
            raise FieldError(
        django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: contains
        [02/Aug/2022 08:37:45] "POST /placeorder HTTP/1.1" 500 118627
```

What I want to do is get all cart objects which has user id = userid and item.restaurant = restaurant id.

I referred to this page: [Django - filtering on foreign key properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981524/django-filtering-on-foreign-key-properties) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not `contains`, it should be `icontains`.

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    userid = request.user.id
    res= request.data.get('restaurant', False)
    cartItem = Cart.objects.filter(user=userid,item__restaurant__icontains=res) # here I changed
    ...
```